# Geolocation assisted ATM monitoring

Tags: oracle, geolocation, oracleforms

we would like to write a web based application to monitor the ATM machines in the bank to have the following functionality:

- Display location of each terminal
- Display general status of the
  terminal in color coding or simple
  icon (ATM up/Down/needs attention,
  low cash, etc.)
- Have a facility to drill down on the 
  status of the machine with more
  details (display counters, up time,
  etc.)
- Have the facility to zoom in the map 
  and pan the map, and to search for
  locations by address or geo location

The status of the machine is available in an Oracle database, and the geolocation is to be added to the terminal definition

is there any ready open source API available to use to implement the above requirements? if there is something for Oracle it would be great

PS: we are looking for an API to support the following countries (UAE and GCC, Kazakhistan, Egypt and North Africa)

Thank you

Comment: would Oracle Application Server have an Oracle Form capable of implementing this feature?

Comment: Oracle MapViewer http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/mapviewer/index.html ?

Comment: thanks for the tip, you should have posted it as an answer to be voted as the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Google's Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), it uses a UI familiar to many people online and it can be customized as you see fit.

**Advantages**

- Easy to use.
- Easy to develop.
- Familiar UI.
- Very customizable.
- Maps updated frequently.

**Disadvantages**

- Requires an internet connection.

Comment: do you think we can use it in an intranet? since the environment we are using is a bank production environment, we can't have it linked to the internet.
we already have an Oracle Application Server and ORacle 10g DB Server on the same system.

Comment: Google's API requires internet access.

Answer (score 1):

At presently in the ATM industry there is no open source solution,,, and basically if you want to write an application consider multivendor specific.The possibilites which you say could be only if all ATM Machines have common interface, from vendor to Vendor it differs.
Do let me know if you have more queries

Comment: I think the best way to do so is to have a customer map defined in a local server.